# how to reduce the file size for uploading?

Tags: angular, angular6

file upload gets a 413 error when uploading a file greater than 40mb.

Here i send the file attachment parameter as an base64string. For a 40mb size file , also gets a long base64 string.

so how could i fix that?

Comment: Depends on how you do that initially ... If you have control over the server, you could just allow bigger uploads. Or you could add the possibility to upload files in different junks. Depending on the content you could also try zipping before uploading it.

Comment: You do not describe what format the server expects. Why do you upload as base64?

Comment: are you want to only compress image or you need to compress other file size also?

Comment: Increase the server file accepting size to 1GB e.g and check Frontend will not restrict any file size-related validations.